# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' Django Middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I am currently new to django framework and I am making a Middleware for authentic redirection of pages within a website. So if the user is guest user I want to always make him redirect to login page. But I came with this error. I have tried **HttpResponse** and **return redirect** but it didn't worked for me.

I am getting this **Attribute error** at all the pages I am accessing to
This shows me along with the error "**'str' object has no attribute 'get'**"

My MiddleWare Code is:

```
import re

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]

if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
   def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
       response = self.get_response(request)
       return response

   def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
       assert hasattr(request, 'user')
       path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
       print(path)

      #if not request.user.is_authenticated:
      #    if not any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS):
      #        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

      url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)
      if path == reverse('logout').lstrip('/'):
          logout(request)
          return redirect('/accounts/')

      if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
          return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

      elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
          return None

      else:
          return(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

This is my link of the error
https://ibb.co/MDZSWWJ

[image]

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: https://ibb.co/MDZSWWJ this is my error problem

Comment: Add it to the question as code-formatted text. No links, no screenshots. And BTW you will find the traceback on the console you are running Django on.

Comment: @NalinDobhal It's a string, not a tuple hence the `'str' object has no attribute…`

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42614172/476

Comment: The problem is `return(settings.LOGIN_URL)`. Use `redirect()` there, like you do elsewhere: `return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)`