# How do you immediately redirect to another view once a view is rendered in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view like below.

```
class ConfirmationPageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "confirmation.html"
```

What I want is to immediately move onto the below view once the `ConfirmationPageView` is loaded (which means its templates were loaded too).

```
class SecondPageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "second.html"
```

I don't care if the user can't see the `ConfirmationPageView` in this very short transition. I just need this confirmation page to show up breifly so that a third party analytics application can track whether a user visited this confirmation page. Thank you, and please leave any questions in the comments.

Comment: This change might be more suited to be done through javascript, as once the template is rendered the views don't have any control of what happens next

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django redirect function.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def view_to_redirect_to(request):
    #This could be the view that handles the display of created objects"
    ....
    perform action here
    return render(request, template, context)

def my_view(request):
    ....
    perform form action here
    return redirect(view_to_redirect_to)
```

This is an example of it in use.
Here is a link to a similar post. [How to redirect from a view to another view In Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614172/how-to-redirect-from-a-view-to-another-view-in-django)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem unfortunately, because `my_view` doesn't render any templates before moving onto the next view.

Comment: Can’t you then just call the view manually.

Comment: Please read my question again. Thank you.

Comment: in your html use script logic "  window.lcoation= your function url "